# 8GB RAM only detected by reboot

Tags: ram

I have an 8GB RAM System but Ubuntu 12.04 only detect 4GB by system start.
Every time I reboot the System Ubuntu will detect the full 8GB RAM!?!?!?

AMD Zacate E350 APU
Radeon HD 6310 512MB shared memory
8GB GSKILL RAM
2TB Segate Barracuda

Comment: Can you post the output of `free -m` by editing your Qn.

Comment: How many modules is it?  Try removing one module, boot the machine, see how much ram is detected, and then try it with the other.  You may have a bad module.

Comment: Can you please post the output of `uname -a`  and `dpkg -l | grep linux-generic`

Comment: regarding @Histo comment: BOTH situations (when on 4 and when on 8 Gb). Maybe 1 mem stick is too slow(?)

Comment: did u enable / install PAE?

Answer (score 1):

You need to run 64bit Ubuntu to address more than 4GB of ram.

Comment: Not exactly true. Ubuntu uses a PAE kernel for 4+Gb and 32bits. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Physical_Address_Extension

Comment: pae kernel is only installed on 12.04 if the installer detects more than 3GB of free ram. I suspect this is the problem he is running a non PAE kernel.

Comment: hmmm and the reboot does activate a pae kernel? :-\ you could be on something there

Answer (score 0):

I think you installed the 32bit version with the `pae` kernel. Enter in the terminal:

```
uname -a
```

If you see `pae` mentioned or `i386`, you are using the 32bit version.
To use the full amount of RAM you need to install the 64bit version.